# Completely disable temp files/temp directory in ClamAV via clamd.conf

Tags: clamav

Is there a way to fully disable the temp files/temp directory feature in ClamAV via clamd.conf such that no files are written to disk, even transiently?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this software can work entirely in RAM. If it can will be vulnerable to kind of memory bomb attack or OOM attack.